# Error: duplicate class: llang.Scope

Tags: java, antlr4

When I compile all my java files for my antlr project, I have a package called llang, and a class, Scope. So, inside my Scope.java file, I have:

```
package llang;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import llang.*;

public class Scope {
    Map<String, Function> memory;
    Map<String, Function> parent;

    public Scope () {
        this(new HashMap<String, Function>());
    }

    public Scope (HashMap<String, Function> parentScope) {
        memory = new HashMap<String, Function>();
        parent = parentScope;
    }

    public void assign (String k, Function v) {
        if (memory.get(k) == null) memory.set(k, v);
    }

    public Function retreive (String k) {
        Function res = memory.get(k);
        if (res == null) return parent.get(k);
        return res;
    }

    public boolean has (String k) {
        return retreive(k) != null;
    }
}
```

And nowhere in my intire project is another "Scope" class or "Scope" file. Yet, when I compile it, it says:

```
./Scope.java:7: error: duplicate class: llang.Scope
public class Scope {
             ^
```

HELP!

Comment: maybe trouble in  this line: `import llang.*;`

Comment: this might be due to 2 classes with the same name in the same package

Comment: Well, did you search your computer for `Scope.java` or `Scope.class`?

Comment: Yes I did search for Scope.java and Scope.class. But there is nothing. Also, I am using ANTLR4, if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

The fix? Remove `import llang.*` and replace with: `import llang.<Whatever other classes>`. Thanks, @AndrewTobilko